# Pygame Creating Sprites While Moving Mouse

Tags: position, mouse, pygame, sprite, space

So, I'm working on a basic Pygame and one of the mechanics is having a bullet sprite follow the mouse and explode. But I'm having just two bugs.

**BUG 1:** Removing the bullets removes all bullets in bullet_list. I understand why this happens but I don't know how to correct it. **Solved**

**BUG 2:** Moving the mouse seems to override the detection of key presses. You cannot move or shoot bullets while moving the mouse.

**Update**

```
#Checking Keys
for event in pygame.event.get():
    print("CAKE")
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            pPlayer.image = pDown
            pPlayer.chy = 2
        elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            pPlayer.image = pUp
            pPlayer.chy = -2
        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            pPlayer.image = pLeft
            pPlayer.chx = -2
        elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            pPlayer.image = pRight
            pPlayer.chx = 2
        elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            if pPlayer.canFire == True:
                bullet = Bullet()
                bullet.rect.x = int(player.x)
                bullet.rect.y = int(player.y)
                all_sprites_list.add(bullet)
                bullet_list.add(bullet)
                pPlayer.canFire = False
        elif event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            if gameState.togglePause == True:
                if gameState.pause == True:
                    gameState.game = True
                    gameState.pause = False
                elif gameState.pause == False:
                    gameState.game = False
                    gameState.pause = True
                gameState.togglePause = False
    elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN or event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            pPlayer.chy = 0
        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            pPlayer.chx = 0
        elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            pPlayer.canFire = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            gameState.togglePause = True
        else:
            pPlayer.chx = 0
            pPlayer.chy = 0
```

**New Bug!** I'm unfamiliar with pygame.event.get() and I'm probably doing something wrong here but the examples provided by the pygame docs don't quite help. I can't tell if it has fixed the handling of multiple events because it doesn't seem to even register them. The code prints out "cake" rarely and very delayed and very seldom do any bullets fire when I hit space.

Comment: The indentation is broke on the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how well this answer applies because your code is only a sample, but I'll do my best.

**Bug 1:** For `if dist < 30`, dist is not updating because you're calculating it in a different for-loop. From your sample, it looks like you can just include the kill check at the end of the first "for bullet in bullet_list" loop.

**Bug 2:** You're only checking for one event per step, so when multiple events happen (ie mouse motion and a keypress) you only handle on of them. To fix this, iterate through a list of all events:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    #Your "Checking Keys" code goes here
```

Comment: Thank you! The bullets not kill themselves properly. But as for Bug 2, I'm trying pygame.event.get(): but it only seems to "get" events rarely and sporadically.

Comment: Always a good practice and good spirit to share the solution to your own question so others may learn. :)